# UnrealEngiine4 First Programming QuickStart try and unexpected (?) results

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, unreal-engine4

Going through the UnrealEngiine4 [Programming QuickStart](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/QuickStart/1/index.html)

and I'm using OSX 10.10.5.
and XCode Version 7.0 (7A220)
and UE4.9.1

When I create the class, and add the code in XCode, I compile.

I get a bunch of warnings - should I care?

They are;

In the QuickStart.xcodeproj:
! Update to recommended settings: 
1 Target 'UE4CmdLineRun' - Adopt "Product Bundle Identifier" build setting
2 Target 'UE4Game - iOS' - Adopt "Product Bundle Identifier" build setting
3 Target 'QuickStart - iOS' - Adopt "Product Bundle Identifier" build setting
these three want to change the Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier key for each
4 Project 'QuickStart' - Turn on "Build Active Architecture Only" when Debugging
5 Project 'QuickStart' - Turn on "Enable Testability" when Debugging

Then: 
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
and others like that

Then, looking at the project document itself, XCode says it's using XCode 3.2-compatible settings.

I have a bunch of questions, but mostly it's about; what the heck is going on? I just installed everything and thought I was ready to go with UE4... so what am I doing wrong? I got as far as step 3.3 in the tutorial.

1. Can I accept the 'Recommended settings'?
2. Can I fix the obsolete resource rules setting?
3. Can I change the project document format to something later than XCode 3.2?

Any guidance on this is well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed in 4.10.4 of UE4 - but I still don't allow the 'suggested settings' to happen. I'll back up and try that as well.